# Github actions gradle in-memory cache misses

Tags: gradle, github-actions

Currently creating a github actions which works fine but I get warnings like this:

```
Performance may suffer from in-memory cache misses. Increase max heap size of Gradle build process to reduce cache misses.
```

When running this github action:

```
name: SonarQube
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master # or the name of your main branch
  pull_request:
    types: [opened, synchronize, reopened]

jobs:
  build:
    name: SonarQube
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          fetch-depth: 0  # Shallow clones should be disabled for a better relevancy of analysis
      - name: Set up JDK 11
        uses: actions/setup-java@v3
        with:
          java-version: 11
          distribution: corretto
          cache: gradle
      - name: Build and analyze
        env:
          SONAR_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.SONAR_TOKEN }}
          SONAR_HOST_URL: ${{ secrets.SONAR_HOST_URL }}
        run: ./gradlew --info sonarqube -Dsonar.host.url=$SONAR_HOST_URL -Dsonar.login=$SONAR_TOKEN
```

What can be changed to make this github actions run without giving said warnings?

Comment: Have you tried doing what the warning suggests?

Comment: @rethab I am not sure how to increase the heapsize on a github action. It works fine when running it locally and in a container